# Changing highlight property of layer or table field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I need to highlight a field of a layer. With ArcMap it is accessed from Fields property page of a layer. From there one can reorder, hide and highlight the fields.

I couldn't find a property or method to change the highlight property of a field.

The FieldInfo Object only allows to set the visibility of a layer. Is there a way to change the highlight property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this existed then I think you would find it amongst the [FieldInfo](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldinfo.htm) properties as you have surmised:

> Provides field info methods and properties for layer and table views.

Since it is not there I think you should submit an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com).  I would target this for ArcGIS Pro rather then the earlier architecture of ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Thanks Polygeo. for your answer. It was not available in FieldInfo properties. I had check that before. Thanks for confirming.